# Combining data from multiple tables when using Group By

Tags: sql

I have data in about 20 different tables. Each table has a column EnterDateTime for the data / time the data in those tables was added. I'm already using a combination of `DATEPART (ISO_WEEK)` and `GROUP BY` to view how much data was added for each week using the following query:

```
SELECT DATEPART (ISO_WEEK, EnterDateTime) WeekNum, COUNT (*) as COUNT
FROM TABLE 1
GROUP BY DATEPART (ISO_WEEK, EnterDateTime)
ORDER BY WeekNum
```

Which is giving results like this, for the data in Table 1:

```
WeekNum | Count
1       | 1084
2       | 5257
3       | 2152
4       | 5172
```

I am then doing the same query on Table 2:

```
WeekNum | Count
1       | 362
2       | 153
3       | 78
4       | 216
```

And so on, and so on, for each of the 20 tables. This is time consuming.

Ideally, I'd like to see this in a single output, like this, so I only have to run one query, instead of about 20:

```
WeekNum | Table 1 Count  | Table 2 Count | Table 3 Count
1       | 1084           | 362           |  x
2       | 5257           | 153           |  x
3       | 2152           | 78            |  x
4       | 5172           | 216           |  x
```

Is this possible? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do all tables always have rows for all weeknums, or can an individual table sometimes have no rows for a given week *(count == 0)*?  Which DBMS are you using?  MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc?  Do the results have to be one column per table_count, or is a normalised result set acceptable *(generally shorter code, more maintainable, more SQL friendly, etc)*.

Comment: @MatBailie,  OP definetly wants one column per table_count.

Comment: I  want one column per table_count @MatBailie. I am using SQL Server

Comment: And what about the zeros?  Your current code never outputs a zero count, instead it just doesn't include that row of data.  Do you need to cater for that?

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a bit of text editing efforts you can create a query type of

```
select WeekNum, min(Count1) Count1,.. min(Count20) Count20
from(
    SELECT DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, EnterDateTime) WeekNum, COUNT (*) as COUNT1, null  as COUNT2, .., null as COUNT20
    FROM TABLE1
    GROUP BY DATEPART (ISO_WEEK, EnterDateTime)

    union all
    ..

    SELECT DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, EnterDateTime) WeekNum, null, .., null, COUNT(*)
    FROM TABLE20
    GROUP BY DATEPART (ISO_WEEK, EnterDateTime)
) t
group by WeekNum
order by WeekNum;
```

Answer (score 1):

The DRYest code I can think of would be to generate the normalised structure, then pivot it.

```
WITH
  combined AS
(
            SELECT 1 AS table_id, EnterDateTime FROM table_1
  UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS table_id, EnterDateTime FROM table_2
  UNION ALL SELECT 3 AS table_id, EnterDateTime FROM table_3
  ...
  UNION ALL SELECT n AS table_id, EnterDateTime FROM table_n
),
  aggregated AS
(
  SELECT
    table_id,
    DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, EnterDateTime)   AS week_num,
    COUNT(*)                            AS row_count
  FROM
    combined
  GROUP BY
    table_id,
    DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, EnterDateTime)
)
SELECT
  week_num,
  MAX(CASE WHEN table_id = 1 THEN row_count END)  AS row_count_1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN table_id = 2 THEN row_count END)  AS row_count_2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN table_id = 3 THEN row_count END)  AS row_count_3,
  ...
  MAX(CASE WHEN table_id = n THEN row_count END)  AS row_count_n
FROM
  aggregated
GROUP BY
  week_num
ORDER BY
  week_num
```

This can be collapsed a bit to two steps...

```
WITH
  combined AS
(
            SELECT 1 AS table_id, EnterDateTime FROM table_1
  UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS table_id, EnterDateTime FROM table_2
  UNION ALL SELECT 3 AS table_id, EnterDateTime FROM table_3
  ...
  UNION ALL SELECT n AS table_id, EnterDateTime FROM table_n
)
SELECT
  DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, EnterDateTime)       AS week_num,
  SUM(CASE WHEN table_id = 1 THEN 1 END)  AS row_count_1,
  SUM(CASE WHEN table_id = 2 THEN 1 END)  AS row_count_2,
  SUM(CASE WHEN table_id = 3 THEN 1 END)  AS row_count_3,
  ...
  SUM(CASE WHEN table_id = n THEN 1 END)  AS row_count_n
FROM
  combined
GROUP BY
  1
ORDER BY
  1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via UNION

```
SELECT DATEPART (ISO_WEEK, EnterDateTime) WeekNum, COUNT (*) as COUNT_TABLE1, count(0) as COUNT_TABLE2, ...
FROM TABLE 1
UNION
SELECT DATEPART (ISO_WEEK, EnterDateTime) WeekNum, COUNT (0) as COUNT_TABLE1, ...
FROM TABLE 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more option, but @Serg's query would probably perform better:

```
;WITH cte
AS(
    SELECT  COALESCE( DATEPART( ISO_WEEK, t1.EnterDateTime), DATEPART (ISO_WEEK, t2.EnterDateTime), DATEPART (ISO_WEEK, t3.EnterDateTime), ...) WeekNum
    ,       t1.[ColumnOnWhichYouCanCount] AS T1, t2.[ColumnOnWhichYouCanCount] AS T2, t3.[ColumnOnWhichYouCanCount] T3, ...
    FROM t1
    FULL JOIN t2 ON DATEPART( ISO_WEEK, t2.EnterDateTime) = DATEPART( ISO_WEEK, t1.EnterDateTime)
    FULL JOIN t3 ON DATEPART( ISO_WEEK, t3.EnterDateTime) = DATEPART( ISO_WEEK, t1.EnterDateTime)
    ...
)
SELECT WeekNum, SUM(T1) AS [Table 1 Count], SUM(T2) AS [Table 2 Count] ...
FROM cte
GROUP BY WeekNum
```

Comment: It's even messier than that.  If you're using `FULL OUTER JOIN`, then you're catering for some weeks having no rows in some tables.  That means that you may have a week where t1 has no data, but t2 and t3 do.  For that you need `t1 FULL t2 ON t2.date = t1.date FULL t3 ON t3.date = COALESCE(t2.date, t1.date) FULL t4 ON t4.date = COALESCE(t3.date, t2.date, t1.date)` and so on...

Comment: @MatBailie, you're right, thanks for your remark, I didn't foresee it. My code will only work if T1 has data for all the weeks. So there is another option to generate one more cte with list of weeks and LEFT JOIN T1, T2, T3,... to it.